# buddypress bp_core_add_message() doesn't fire why?

Tags: buddypress

Ok I have the following php which work ok as in it run through to the IF but no matter what i do I can't get the bp_core message to fire on screen it just gives me the changes saved message... 
why what am i doing wrong!

```
    function valid_postcode ($self) {
    $getFieldID = $self->field_id;
    $PostCodeFieldID = 23;
    $postcodecheck = $_POST['field_23'];
 if ( $getFieldID == $PostCodeFieldID || $postcodecheck == ''){

        $GetValuePost = $self->value;

        $regex = '/[a-z][0-9][a-z][- ]?[0-9][a-z][0-9]$/i';  

    if(!preg_match($regex, $GetValuePost)) {

       bp_core_add_message( __( 'That Postcode  is invalid. Check the formatting and try again.', 'buddypress' ), 'error' );

    }elseif (!isset($getFieldID)) {

       bp_core_add_message( __( 'You need to fill out the post code.', 'buddypress' ), 'error' );

    }
  }

}
add_action( 'xprofile_data_before_save', 'valid_postcode', 1, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages posted with `bp_core_add_message()` are stored in a cookie, and then rendered to the screen at the `'template_notices'` hook (either on the current pageload, or the next one, whichever comes first). It's likely that the template you're using doesn't fire `'template_notices'`.

Comment: it did have the template notices, I ended up having to unhook and rehook the filter...